# PoseWarping: How to vectorize this for loop (z-buffer)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch

I'm trying to warp a frame from view1 to view2 using ground truth depth map, pose information, and camera matrix. I've been able to remove most of the for-loops and vectorize it, except one for-loop. When warping, multiple pixels in view1 may get mapped to a single location in view2, due to occlusions. In this case, I need to pick the pixel with the lowest depth value (foreground object). I'm not able to vectorize this part of the code. Any help to vectorize this for loop is appreciated.

#### Context:

I'm trying to warp an image into a new view, given ground truth pose, depth, and camera matrix. After computing warped locations, I'm rounding them off. Any suggestions to implement inverse bilinear interpolation are also welcome. My images are of full HD resolution. Hence it is taking a lot of time to warp the frames to the new view. If I can vectorize, I'm planning to convert the code to TensorFlow or PyTorch and run it on a GPU. Any other suggestions to speed up warping, or existing implementations are also welcome.

#### Code:

```
def warp_frame_04(frame1: numpy.ndarray, depth: numpy.ndarray, intrinsic: numpy.ndarray, transformation1: numpy.ndarray,
                  transformation2: numpy.ndarray, convert_to_uint: bool = True, verbose_log: bool = True):
    """
    Vectorized Forward warping. Nearest Neighbor.
    Offset requirement of warp_frame_03() overcome.
    mask: 1 if pixel found, 0 if no pixel found
    Drawback: Nearest neighbor, collision resolving not vectorized
    """
    height, width, _ = frame1.shape
    assert depth.shape == (height, width)
    transformation = numpy.matmul(transformation2, numpy.linalg.inv(transformation1))

    y1d = numpy.array(range(height))
    x1d = numpy.array(range(width))
    x2d, y2d = numpy.meshgrid(x1d, y1d)
    ones_2d = numpy.ones(shape=(height, width))
    ones_4d = ones_2d[:, :, None, None]
    pos_vectors_homo = numpy.stack([x2d, y2d, ones_2d], axis=2)[:, :, :, None]

    intrinsic_inv = numpy.linalg.inv(intrinsic)
    intrinsic_4d = intrinsic[None, None]
    intrinsic_inv_4d = intrinsic_inv[None, None]
    depth_4d = depth[:, :, None, None]
    trans_4d = transformation[None, None]

    unnormalized_pos = numpy.matmul(intrinsic_inv_4d, pos_vectors_homo)
    world_points = depth_4d * unnormalized_pos
    world_points_homo = numpy.concatenate([world_points, ones_4d], axis=2)
    trans_world_homo = numpy.matmul(trans_4d, world_points_homo)
    trans_world = trans_world_homo[:, :, :3]
    trans_norm_points = numpy.matmul(intrinsic_4d, trans_world)
    trans_pos = trans_norm_points[:, :, :2, 0] / trans_norm_points[:, :, 2:3, 0]
    trans_pos_int = numpy.round(trans_pos).astype('int')

    # Solve occlusions
    a = trans_pos_int.reshape(-1, 2)
    d = depth.ravel()
    b = numpy.unique(a, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    collision_indices = b[1][b[2] >= 2]  # Unique indices which are involved in collision
    for c1 in tqdm(collision_indices, disable=not verbose_log):
        cl = a[c1].copy()  # Collision Location
        ci = numpy.where((a[:, 0] == cl[0]) & (a[:, 1] == cl[1]))[0]  # Colliding Indices: Indices colliding for cl
        cci = ci[numpy.argmin(d[ci])]  # Closest Collision Index: Index of the nearest point among ci
        a[ci] = [-1, -1]
        a[cci] = cl
    trans_pos_solved = a.reshape(height, width, 2)

    # Offset both axes by 1 and set any out of frame motion to edge. Then crop 1-pixel thick edge
    trans_pos_offset = trans_pos_solved + 1
    trans_pos_offset[:, :, 0] = numpy.clip(trans_pos_offset[:, :, 0], a_min=0, a_max=width + 1)
    trans_pos_offset[:, :, 1] = numpy.clip(trans_pos_offset[:, :, 1], a_min=0, a_max=height + 1)

    warped_image = numpy.ones(shape=(height + 2, width + 2, 3)) * numpy.nan
    warped_image[trans_pos_offset[:, :, 1], trans_pos_offset[:, :, 0]] = frame1
    cropped_warped_image = warped_image[1:-1, 1:-1]
    mask = numpy.isfinite(cropped_warped_image)
    cropped_warped_image[~mask] = 0
    if convert_to_uint:
        final_warped_image = cropped_warped_image.astype('uint8')
    else:
        final_warped_image = cropped_warped_image
    mask = mask[:, :, 0]
    return final_warped_image, mask
```

#### Code Explanation

- I'm using the equations[1,2] to get pixel locations in view2
- Once I have the pixel locations, I need to figure out if there are any occlusions and if so, I have to pick the foreground pixels.
- `b = numpy.unique(a, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)` gives me unique locations.
- If multiple pixels from view1 map to a single pixel in view2 (collision), `return_counts` will give a value greater than 1.
- `collision_indices = b[1][b[2] >= 2]` gives indices which are involved in collision. Note that this gives only one index per collision.
- For each of such collision points, `ci = numpy.where((a[:, 0] == cl[0]) & (a[:, 1] == cl[1]))[0]` provides indices of all pixels from view1 which map to the same point in view2.
- `cci = ci[numpy.argmin(d[ci])]` gives the pixel index with lowest depth value.
- `a[ci] = [-1, -1]` and `a[cci] = cl` maps all other background pixels to location (-1,-1) which is out of frame and hence will be ignored.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1D9t.png
[2] https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/69890/32876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this as follows. Instead of picking the nearest point (min), I used soft-min, i.e. I took the weighted average of all the colliding points where I made sure that a small difference in depth leads to a large difference in weights and that the nearest depth has the highest weight. I implemented the sum (in soft-min) using [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65038790/3337089).

I was able to further port it to PyTorch using [`torch.Tensor.index_put_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_put_) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089). Finally, I replaced the rounding-off (nearest neighbour interpolation) with bilinear splatting (inverse bilinear interpolation). Both numpy and torch implementations are available [here](https://github.com/NagabhushanSN95/Pose-Warping).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do image processing (which you are) in 99.9% of the cases you run into edge cases that are not covered by default Numpy functions. I'm not sure how you can vectorize that code using Numpy, but you don't have to. Have a look at Cython. It allows you to create custom C++ extensions (which is what Numpy is really). You can start from your base Python code and gradually add typing information as well as disabling Python-specific checks (for example disable wraparounds and boundscheck). These can lead to crashes so do the optimizations one at a time and make sure to test each step. If your code is parallelizable (which to me it seems it is) and you are comfortable with multi threading, you can release the GIL (with nogil:) and pass in the original array, an offset and a count to your Cython function to operate on the shared memory with different threads (using the built-in thread pool usually works very nicely). Let me know if you want to follow this path so I can add more details and code snippets to this answer or if you prefer to stick with Numpy.

Comment: Thanks for an alternate solution. This might be useful in some other tasks. I have already implemented my question above. Instead of picking the nearest point (min), I used soft-min i.e. I took the weighted average of all the colliding points where I made sure that a small difference in depth leads to a large difference in weights and that the nearest depth has the highest weight. I implemented the sum (in soft-min) using [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65038790/3337089).

Comment: I was able to further port it to PyTorch using [`torch.Tensor.index_put_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_put_) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089). Finally, I replaced the rounding-off (nearest neighbour interpolation) with bilinear splatting (inverse bilinear interpolation). Both numpy and torch implementations are available [here](https://github.com/NagabhushanSN95/Pose-Warping).

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve this, but again, if you're trying to leverage GPU power you can write your own CUDA extensions which is a bit more involved than writing Cython extensions but from my experience it is worthwhile as it leads to cleaner code that does the minimum amount of work required, instead of having to conform to what is available in other libraries. Are you using this as part of an ML pipeline or are you using Pytorch just to accelerate using a GPU?

Comment: Actually, this is just for academic research. With numpy vectorization, the code was fast enough for me. Later, I ported the code to pytorch so that I can use this code as part of my deep learning model by allowing gradients to back propagate through this warping.

Comment: I agree that in time critical cases, it might be worthwhile to implement this in cuda or cython.