# Add a index selected numpy array to another numpy array with overlapping indices

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, vectorization

I have two numpy arrays `image` and `warped_image` and indices arrays `ix,iy`. I need to add `image` to `warped_image` such that `image[i,j]` is added to `warped_image[iy[i,j],ix[i,j]]`. The below code works if the pairs `(iy[i,j], ix[i,j])` are unique for all `i,j`. But when they are not unique i.e. when 2 elements from `image` need to be added to the same element in `warped_image`, only one of them gets added. How can I add both elements from `image` to the same element in `warped_image`?

Note that, I don't want to use any `for` loops. I want to keep this vectorized. I'm planning to convert the code to TensorFlow or PyTorch in the future to use GPU capabilities for this. That's because, I have hundreds of such images and each image is of full HD resolution.

```
import numpy
image = numpy.array([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
iy = numpy.array([[1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 2]])
ix = numpy.array([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
warped_image = numpy.zeros(shape=image.shape)
warped_image[iy, ix] += image

>> warped_image
Out[31]: 
array([[  113., 110.,  50.],
       [246., 116.,   1.],
       [187., 101.,  64.]])
```

For the above case, indices are unique and hence the output is as expected.

```
import numpy
image = numpy.array([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
iy = numpy.array([[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
ix = numpy.array([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
warped_image = numpy.zeros(shape=image.shape)
warped_image[iy, ix] += image

>> warped_image
Out[32]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   1.],
       [246., 116.,   0.],
       [187., 110.,  64.]])
```

Expected Output:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   51.],
       [246., 116.,   0.],
       [300., 211.,  64.]])
```

In this case, there are 3 pairs of indices which overlap and hence it fails. E.g. `image[0,1]` and `image[1,1]` should gt added to `warped_image[0,2]` to give a value 51. However only one of them (`image[1,1]`) gets added to give a value 1.

**Context**:
I'm trying to do warp an image from view1 to view2. I've computed which pixel has to go where. In case of overlapping pixels, I need to take a weighted average of them. So, I need to achieve the above. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65031764/3337089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.add.at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
import numpy
image = numpy.array([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
iy = numpy.array([[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
ix = numpy.array([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
warped_image = numpy.zeros(shape=image.shape)

np.add.at(warped_image, (iy, ix), image)

print(warped_image)
```

**Output**

```
[[  0.   0.  51.]
 [246. 116.   0.]
 [300. 211.  64.]]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I've been stuck here for far too long. Any idea if this functionality is implemented in TensorFlow or PyTorch?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389822/equivalent-for-np-add-at-in-tensorflow) can help